# How to match one word only within double quotes

Tags: regex

I was trying to match one word within double quotes but not outside. For instance:

```
"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx " , OneWord ; OneWord, "xxxxx , OneWord xxxxx". " OneWord 1" ----  " OneWord 2":
```

The expected match I need is 
*`"xxxxx , OneWord xxxxx"`*
*`" OneWord 1"`*
*`" OneWord 2"`*

I had tried this

```
"(?:(?!OneWord)[^"])*(?(?=")\"\K|OneWord[^"]*")
```

Finally, I realized that the quotes not containing the OneWord match and it's
just not showed. ex:"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx ". it matches but not showed.
What I need is just to have the quotes containing the OneWord matched.

Is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried and is a comma inside the double quotes really wanted?

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but I don't want the quotes like this "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx " matched, as there is no OneWord inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
"[^"]*\bOneWord\b[^"]*"(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

**Explanation**

- `"[^"]*` Match `"` followed by 0+ occurrences of any char except `"`
- `\bOneWord\b` Match `OneWord` between word boundaries
- `[^"]*"` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `"`, then match `"`
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is at the right

  - `(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*` Optionally match pairs of double quotes
  - `[^"]*$` Match an optional trailing part without `"` till the end of the string
- `)` Close lookahead

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZeIGZ/1)

Or a bit longer version accepting an escaped double quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFXSyc/1)